# Android - How to set the wallpaper image?

Tags: android, wallpaper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - how to set the wallpaper image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image)

What i'm trying to do is, set the wallpaper using an image URI (no cropping)

I'm a noob at dev on Android and dev in general.
The internet has failed me... on providing code to set the wallpaper.

*yes* the dev resource site says

`public void setStream (InputStream data)`

but i don't understand it, some sample code would greatly help me.

Comment: Related: [Android - how to set the wallpaper image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964193/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image)

Answer (score 11):

Hi you can use this code if You have Image path.

```
is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
bitmap.recycle();
if(imagePath!=null){
    System.out.println("Hi I am try to open Bit map");
    wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
```

---

if you have image URI then use this

```
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
mImageView.setImageURI(imagepath);
```

---

Let me know if there is  any issue .

Comment: whats the use of this line? wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

Answer (score 3):

If you have the image URL you can open the resource it represent using the stream(abstraction):
`new URL("your.image.url.com").openStream()`. This method call will return an object of type `InputStream` which you can pass as an argument to `setStream()` method.

If you dont want to specify a stream directly, you can open the remote stream, create a Bitmap and then either use a [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) instance or do a `context.setWallpaper(bitmap)`(this is deprecated) to set your bitmap as the wallpaper.

For reference take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098548/android-save-image-from-web-server-and-set-it-as-wallpaper/2099068#2099068) thread.

Comment: This is my current code...

InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

bgImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Context context = this.getBaseContext();

context.setWallpaper(bgImage);`

Errors at bgImage (line 2 and 4) and getBaseContext() (line 3)

also whats the difference between a URI and a URL?
Short answer i got was "A URL is a URI but, a URI is not a URL"

Comment: ok i fixed the errors on lines 2 and 4, i didn't define the Bitmap bgImage. but still errors on getBaseContext()

Comment: You know you can pass an instance of Activity as Context right? No need to do a this.getBaseContext() you can pass instance of current activity or a context object if you have one["this" would be a valid context object]

Comment: And yes there is difference between URI and URL..

Comment: i am getting here  --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null..any suggestion here