# Setting live wallpaper programmatically

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to set a live wallpaper using some lines of code. For example, i want to tell my users that a live wallpaper is available "click here to set it".

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you can launch the wallpaper-selector but you can't set the Wallpaper directly.

Comment: So i guess my next question is .. how to launch it using code?

Comment: It seems that it is possible to set the wallpaper directly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205092/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image

Comment: @mahboudz that's only possible for static wallpapers (images) not livewallpapers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alright, just so I stop getting downvotes for an outdated answer.  Please see Error 454's answer below for a more robust solution which will send the user directly to the wallpaper preview screen on Jelly Bean and up devices.

========================================

Here's how to start the wallpaper chooser, from which the user can select your wallpaper.  The toast is just a way to explain to the user what's going on.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Choose '<WALLPAPER NAME>' from the list to start the Live Wallpaper.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can I change it without user interaction? Can you please check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-on-rooted-device-android

Comment: No, you can't.  Error454's answer is as close as it gets without rooting.  I don't know how you'd do it with root, though.  Maybe ask around on XDA.

Answer (score 34):

There are now two ways to accomplish this as Jelly Bean provides a way to directly set the live wallpaper.  This boilerplate code will choose the best method available.

```
Intent i = new Intent();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
    i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

    String p = HypercaneWallpaperService.class.getPackage().getName();
    String c = HypercaneWallpaperService.class.getCanonicalName();        
    i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(p, c));
}
else{
    i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
}
getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Comment: And what if I don't own that wallpaper? I mean how to set another wallpaper using my application? can you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-on-rooted-device-android

Comment: My wallpaper service was in another package than the main package. The correct package I had to supply was: String String p = this.getContext().getPackageName();

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [async_wallpaper](https://pub.dev/packages/async_wallpaper) package to perform this operation. You can easily access the mp4 files through URLs and show them in your app and also apply them on the home screen

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to get wallpaper manager to set wallpaper. Here is the code that is used in one of my apps, It uses AsyncTask (which is deprecated) but you can implement with Kotlin coroutines as well.

```
class SetWallpaperTask : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, Bitmap?>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): Bitmap? {
        val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        var result: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            result =
                Glide.with(this@WallpaperPreviewActivity).asBitmap().load(fullhdurl).submit()
                    .get()
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return result
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        Toast.makeText(this@WallpaperPreviewActivity, "Wallpaper Applied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        // show progress bar or dialog
    }
}
```