# Set Android live wallpaper by code, without user interaction

Tags: android, service, live-wallpaper

I want to automatically set the live wallpaper in Android by code, without any user interface for wallpaper selection.

Simple wallpaper setting automatically setting is possible by code:

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable(); 
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
imageView.setImageDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

Now I have to set Live Wallpaper automatically using a service, such that Live Wallpaper should be set automatically everyday on screen.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Android OS does not allow you to programatically set live wallpaper. You can do that only for static wallpaper. The closest you can get is use this method: [Setting live wallpaper programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831499/setting-live-wallpaper-programatically).

Comment: Thanks for this reply,Lot of R&d now decide Android OS does not allowing us to programatically set live wallpaper. How i know this thing is not supportable for android OS? if you having any slandered URL for this limitation then kindly share to me.

Comment: Jelly Bean now supports changing the Live Wallpaper programtically without user interaction :)

Comment: @Adnan Mulla Can you please tell me how?