# How do i get the selected live wallpaper on android?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I successfully retrieved the selected wallpaper from wallpaper manager and applied it to my app background with this code:

`

```
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutParent);

    final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

    parent.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

`

But this code doesn't work if the selected wallpaper is a live wallpaper, i just searched for a solution in google and didn't find any.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831499/1465828)

Comment: Are you trying to set a live wallpaper as a background animated image inside your application?

Comment: Yes that´s what i am trying do you have any idea how?