# What does it mean for a method to be deprecated, and how can I resolve resulting errors?

Tags: java, android, android-wallpaper

Why do I get a deprecation error on the line containing `setWallpaper(bmp)`, and how can I resolve it?

> Error: The method setWallpaper(Bitmap) from the type Context is deprecated

```
switch(v.getId()){
 case R.id.bSetWallpaper:
try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
```

Comment: I think you've made a mistake in your question. Can you clarify the error for us please?

Comment: Yeah sorry I have edited the post, missed it out by accident.

Comment: "deprecated" means you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When something is deprecated, it means the developers have created a better way of doing it and that you should no longer be using the old, or deprecated way. Things that are deprecated are subject to removal in the future.

In your case, the correct way to set the wallpaper if you have an image path is as follows:

```
is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
bitmap.recycle();
if(imagePath!=null){
    System.out.println("Hi I am try to open Bit map");
    wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
```

If you have an image URI, then use the following:

```
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
mImageView.setImageURI(imagepath);
```

From Maidul's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205092/android-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-image) question.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into trying this when I get back to the code.

Answer (score 5):

"Deprecated" means that the particular code you are using is no longer the recommended method of achieving that functionality. You should look at the documentation for your given method, and it will more than likely provide a link to the recommended method in it's place.

Answer (score 3):

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, 
                   "Ooops, couldn't set the wallpaper", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WallpaperManager.setStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) instead of Context.setWallpaper() as it is deprecated and may be removed in new API releases.