# creating a server side wallpaper app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wallpaper

am new to android and I am interested in creating an app where I can put the pictures on a server and then call them from the app itself, i have looked and looked for documentation on this but have had no luck. i was hoping that someone could point me into the right direction. i have seen notable apps that use flicker as their pictures. does anyone know how of any documentation that would help me?

```
<

WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

so far a web view is the only similar thing i have found but i honestly do not think am on the right direction, any help would be very apreciated, am looking to place at least 5000 images not only one
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to save the image and use [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). See the following link for information.

[android - save image from web server and set it as wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098548/android-save-image-from-web-server-and-set-it-as-wallpaper)

Comment: hi thank you for your anwser but i have a question what if i have thouthads of images do i have to hand code everysingle one of them?